# Can't change element dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to understand why I can't change element's width or height. 
I was using jquery [textfill](https://github.com/jquery-textfill/jquery-textfill) library until another jquery library was added that broke it. After debugging I found that it's because my `$('.msg-text span:first')` element's `width` is `0`. That was the first weird thing, because in element inspector it's width wasn't 0. Also the height was different. Without much thinking, I set it's width to 100, because the library would change it anyway. But that doesn't do anything. I mean - here is the output from chrome developer tools:

```
$('.msg-text span:first').width();
0
$('.msg-text span:first').width(100);
[<span data-in-effect=​"bounceIn" data-in-delay=​"30" data-in-delayscale=​"1" data-out-delay=​"30" data-out-delayscale=​"1" data-out-effect=​"bounceOut" data-out-reverse=​"true" class=​"ng-binding" style=​"display:​ initial;​visibility:​ visible;​ font-size:​ 302px;​ height:​ 100px;​ width:​ 100px;​">​…​</span>​]
$('.msg-text span:first').width();
0
```

Same goes for height. Tried with other element's and it's fine. The moment when it's width is set to 0 is when 2nd library insert content in it with `element.html()`

If more details are required I will be pleased to provide them.
One more weird thing is that for that specific page I am writing, if stop code in some particular places, dom highlighting doesn't work and when I stop the code when I check for element's width, I see only it's shape (with those dotted lines), and setting it's background doesn't show it either. I doubt that this is related, but who knows...

Comment: Add display:block/inline-block

Comment: @Akxe heh, those little things... :D You could submit this as an answer, because it solved this, thanks!

Comment: Way to small to be an answer ;) glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it work you should probably add 'display: block' or 'display: inline-block' to the element.